# Calculating voltages of output and feedback voltage divider in OpAmp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've been trying to calculate Vout as shown in the diagram, but I am struggling to understand the way that the circuit is wired. I need to calculate it for switch S in the lower and upper position. I realize that there is no current flowing through the virtual ground. I am confused as to why Vout, Vin, and R4 are not connected, and what "upper" and "lower" position means for the switch.

[image: Schematic showing an operational amplifier circuit with negative feedback]

Answer (score 1):

Two cases:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9kbxM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is in either the lower position or the upper position, \$V_{in}\$ sets up a current into the virtual node that is \$\cfrac{V_{in}}{R_1}\$. (Call that current positive if \$V_{in}\$ is positive.)

When the switch is in the lower position, the opamp must pull all that current through both \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$. But to do that, the voltage at the output of the opamp has to be of an opposing sign. So the opamp output, and output voltage, will be:

$$-\cfrac{V_{opamp}}{R_2+R_3}=\cfrac{V_{in}}{R_1},\:\:\:\therefore V_{out}=V_{opamp}=-V_{in}\cfrac{R_2+R_3}{R_1}$$

However, when the switch is in the upper position, the opamp must still pull all that current through \$R_2\$. But not necessarily through \$R_3\$, as the load may also be sinking or sourcing current. So now, the output voltage will instead be:

$$-\cfrac{V_{out}}{R_2}=\cfrac{V_{in}}{R_1},\:\:\:\therefore V_{out}=-V_{in}\cfrac{R_2}{R_1}$$

The output at the opamp will have to be:

$$-\cfrac{V_{opamp}-V_{out}}{R_3}=\cfrac{V_{in}}{R_1}-I_{load},\:\:\:\therefore V_{opamp}=-\left[V_{in}\cfrac{R_2+R_3}{R_1} + I_{load}\cdot R_3\right]$$

You will need to make sure the opamp has sufficient voltage compliance, in either case.

With the values shown in your diagram, you will have \$V_{out}=-20\:\textrm{V}\$ with the switch in the lower position and \$V_{out}=-8\:\textrm{V}\$ with the switch in the upper position. You can also see that in the upper position, and with a positive input voltage and with a positive load current, the opamp will have to have an output voltage with a larger negative magnitude than if there were no load current at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused as to why Vout, Vin, and R4 are not connnected

\$V_{out}\$ is the voltage between the right-most terminal of the switch \$S\$ and ground.  If it helps you conceptually, place a voltmeter across the two terminals where the label \$V_{out}\$ is and consider the voltage measured to be the voltage \$V_{out}\$.

\$V_{in}\$, on the other hand, is a *stimulus* and so you can place a voltage source across the terminals where the label \$V_{in}\$ is and then label the source \$V_{in}\$.

Both terminals of \$R_4\$ are connected so I'm not sure if that's a typo or if you don't see that they are.

Finally, a better home for questions like this is the EE stack exchange site which includes a schematic editor which would allow an answer to easily include a schematic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a circuit diagram of a circuit element, in this case an inverting operational amplifier that has been configured to amplify a specific signal (Vin) and output it at a certain level (Vout). Firstly, R4 is connected to ground. Vin and Vout are not connected, because the circuit diagram is only concerned with the operational amplifier configuration. When solving for the properties of the circuit you simply assume that you are applying a signal at the Vin terminal and receiving an output at the Vout terminal.

Upper and lower position refers to the path the output signal would take. If the switch is in the upper position the connection will be made to the path that includes R3, if the switch is in the lower position the signal will pass by the R3.

Answer (score 0):

The op-amp inverting input is at a virtual ground (as you seem to know). With a 20mV supply at Vin, then you know that 20mV/1\$\Omega\$ = 20mA is flowing through R1. The value of R4 is irrelevant for an ideal op-amp (and non-ideal for an non-ideal op-amp- it should be closer to 1 ohm).

Since an ideal op-amp has no input current, that same current must be flowing through R2 + R2. We are going to assume that nothing is attached to Vout except an ideal voltmeter that has infinite input impedance.

The switch is a two position switch that can be set the upper position as SW1 below or the lower position as SW2 below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fift2m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, the switch does not change the way current flows, it merely selects a different connection to Vout.

Since a known current of 20mA flows through both R2 and R3 in series and we know what voltage is at the left side of R2 (0V) we can easily calculate the voltages at the Vout in either position. The only thing a bit tricky is to notice what the sign is (the output voltage will be negative for positive input voltage).

In the upper position, the voltage output is that across R2 only. In the lower position the voltage output is that across R2+R3.

So the output voltage Vout is -20V in the lower switch position (and in fact that's always the voltage at the op-amp output) and Vout is -8V with the switch in the upper position.

Here is another way to represent the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBT4eq.png)</sup>

If you run the Circuitlab simulation you can move the switch to either position and read the output voltage. It will be almost exactly the predicted values because the particular op-amp I chose is almost ideal under DC conditions.